# Cannot connect to websites

Tags: internet

My Pi is behind a proxy. I am able to download packages using `apt-get` command.

However, when I use something like this:

```
curl https://www.dataplicity.com/iam1o1sx.py | sudo python
```

There is an error:

> Could not resolve host: www.dataplicity.com

I have entered my credentials (user name:password @ proxy) for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP in `10proxy` file.

What could the problem be?

Comment: How is the Pi and the proxy server getting DNS? That is what the error is hinting at. This may help as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/linux-curl-command-with-proxy

Comment: I tried typing in 'export https_proxy=https://your.proxy.server:port/' in the terminal window of pi. Then I tried the same curl command as mentioned in the question. It shows a message " Received http code 407 after connect".

Comment: You need to authenticate with the proxy. If you are not planning to use curl in the finished product you may be chasing problems that don't exist. as Dimitry pointed out the cause of the error is that curl is not aware of the proxy and the 407 error is because you are not authenticated on the proxy from curl.

Answer (score 7):

`curl` has no idea about `10proxy` file, which is exclusive to `apt` package manager.

You should either specify your proxy in [`http_proxy`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#httpproxy) environment variable, or using [`--proxy`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x) command line switch.

PS. HTTP error 407 means: "Proxy authentication required". Obviously, you forgot to specify your username and password, like this:

```
export https_proxy=user:password@server:port
```

Incidentally, if you happen to have special characters like `:` or `@` in your password, you might be interested to know [how to encode them](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: As you suggested, I typed in with username and password. Now, I am getting another error - "Received HTTP cod3 403 after connect"

Comment: @AbhilashA Then maybe you're trying to download a file [you don't have access to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)?

Comment: Yes, you were right I tried another link and it worked. But, I am not able to load any website using chromium browser in pi

Comment: @AbhilashA That sounds like an unrelated issue to me. Anyway, did you set up chromium to use your proxy?

Comment: No. I did not. How do I setup chromium to use proxy?

Comment: @AbhilashA Copy your comment in Google and push `I'm feeling lucky!`

Comment: Good answer, @DmitryGrigoryev - I just entered: `chromium how to setup proxy` into `duckduckgo.com` and found this page: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-settings